# How to iterate through ArrayList and cast the returned object into another object

Tags: c#

(this is an academic problem)

I created an Arraylist to hold student objects. Now I need to cast them back to original type and print out on the console.  I need to create a method in an object that would loop through all objects (after they have been cast back) and print them out -

How do I cast a returned object from the ArrayList to a (Student) object.

In course object I created an ArrayList called studentarraylist

```
public class Course
        {
            ArrayList studentarraylist = new ArrayList();
```

In that course object I created a method to add student

```
public void AddStudent(Student student)
            {
                studentarraylist.Add(student);          
             }
```

In main - I added a student object to the ArrayList using that method

```
course.AddStudent(student1);
```

Now I need to create a method in Course to cast objects back to original type, using a foreach loop iterate over the Students in the ArrayList and output their first and last names to the console window.  I got a bit mixed up as I don't have access to some items in the method - when I created them in main.

```
public void liststudents(ArrayList studentarraylist)
            {
                Course studentoneout = (Course)studentarraylist[0];


                 for (int i = 0; i < studentarraylist.Count; ++i)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(studentarraylist[i]);
                    Console.WriteLine("student first name", studentarraylist.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
```

edit ***

```
public class Course
        {
            ArrayList studentarraylist = new ArrayList();

            private string courseName;
            //Create a course name          
            public string CourseName
            {
                get { return courseName; }
                set { courseName = value; }
            }       

            //add student method
            public void AddStudent(Student student)
            {
                studentarraylist.Add(student);          
             }



             public void liststudents(ArrayList studentarraylist)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < studentarraylist.Count; i++)
                {
                    Student currentStudent = (Student)studentarraylist[i];
                    Console.WriteLine("Student First Name: {0}", currentStudent.FirstName); // Assuming FirstName is a property of your Student class
                    Console.WriteLine("Student Last Name: {0}", currentStudent.LastName);
                    // Output what ever else you want to the console.
                }

                 // Course studentoneout = (Course)studentarraylist[0];





//                 for (int i = 0; i < studentarraylist.Count; ++i)
 //               {
  //                  Student s = (Student)studentarraylist[i];

   //             }
            }
```

Comment: You expected that studentarraylist is the list of Student, but i saw you cast object to Course???

Comment: my code might not be super clean - I was trying a few things.  I was trying to add the items in Course but it didn't work and added them in main instead.  I was trying to cast them to original type but got no where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, but it looks like your `liststudents()` is the problem.  When you pull an items off of your `studentarraylist` you should be casting it into a `Student` object, and not a `Course` object.

### EDIT

Take out the paramenter from the `liststudents()`, because your `Course` class already has the `ArrayList` defined in it.  You shouldn't have to pass an `ArrayList` to your class that your class already knows about.

```
public void liststudents()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < studentarraylist.Count; i++) 
    {
        Student currentStudent = (Student)studentarraylist[i];
        Console.WriteLine("Student First Name: {0}", currentStudent.FirstName); // Assuming FirstName is a property of your Student class
        Console.WriteLine("Student Last Name: {0}", currentStudent.LastName);
        // Output what ever else you want to the console.
    }
}
```

Then you would use liststudents() from main like so...

```
Course myCourse = new Course();
myCourse.AddStudent(someNewStudentYouMade);
myCourse.AddStudent(someNewStudentYouMade);
myCourse.AddStudent(someNewStudentYouMade);
myCourse.AddStudent(someNewStudentYouMade);
myCourse.AddStudent(someNewStudentYouMade);
myCourse.liststudents();
```

Comment: that sort of looks right but I am still getting my head around it.  it looks like it is casting to orignal type and then printing out first and last name !!  - what would I pass in to course.liststudents(); ?

Comment: @Aindriu I thought the liststudents() was in your Course class?  Can you post your Course class and Student class?

Comment: Yes it is in Course but I was calling the method course.liststudent() from main.

Comment: wow ! that worked.  I just hope it is casting before printing out

Answer (score 5):

You should not be using `ArrayList` for this, to begin with. Generic `List<Student>` is what you need for your list here.

However if you have to stick to `ArrayList`, it does not contain any `Course` objects, only `Student` ones. So the first cast should fail:

`(Course)studentarraylist[0]`

Now, if you want to call student specific methods on the items of the list, you need to make sure to cast them to correct type, `Student` in this case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentarraylist.Count; ++i)
{
    Student s = (Student)studentarraylist[i];
    ...
}
```

Also, if you want to iterate over students you've already added, you do not need to pass anything to `liststudents` - you already have a field in the class instance to work with. So it should be

```
public void liststudents()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < studentarraylist.Count; ++i)
    {
        Student s = (Student)studentarraylist[i];
        ...
    }
}
```

And the usageof the `Course` class:

```
Course c = new Course();
c.AddStudent(student1);
c.AddStudent(student2);
c.liststudents();
```

Last thing - unless there is a hard reason to do so, do not use no-caps names like `liststudents`. It should be `ListStudents` according to C# standards.

Answer (score 1):

In your for-loop, you're not actually printing out the student, but the entire list.

One way to solve this is just print out the name of the student at the position i like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentarraylist.Count; ++i)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("student first name", studentarraylist[i].Name.ToString());
         Console.WriteLine("");
    }
```

Comment: Since the OP is using an ArrayList, it's probably not a good idea to use a foreach to iterate through the ArrayList, because there is no guarantee that all objects in the ArrayList are of type Student.

Comment: they are all of type student and I need to use the foreach loop

Comment: @Shar1er80 You're right, i'll remove that part from my answer. However, OP should be using a `List<Student>` as the top answer says.

Comment: Then as @Andrei has suggested, you should be using a List<> from the System.Collections.Generic namespace.  You would have a List<Student> inside your Course class, then you wouldn't have to bother with any casting.

Answer (score 1):

> Using foreach - **implicit cast**

If it's in main

```
foreach (Student student in MyCourseObject.Students)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName);
}
```

If inside Course class

```
public void ListStudents()
    {
        foreach (Student s in this.Students)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", s.FirstName, s.LastName);
        }
    }
```

> Using for loop - **explicit cast**

In main

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyCourseObject.Students.Count; i++)
{
    Student student = (Student)MyCourseObject.Students[i];
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName);
}
```

If inside Course Class

```
public void ListStudents()
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < this.Students.Count; i++)
         {
             Student student = (Student)this.Students[i];
             Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName);
         }
     }
```

**for this assume that:**

- There is a Student ArrayList defined in the Course Class.
- MyCourseObject is an Instance of Course class.
- Students is the Arraylist which contains objects(instances) of type Student.